# Determine a Registry Key's Object Name

Tags: c++, winapi, registry

I am attempting to set the Discretionary Access Control List(DACL) for a Registry Key using the function [SetNamedSecurityInfo()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379579%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

I'm not sure what the first parameter `pObjectName` should be for this function if I am setting a Registry Key? What I am also not sure about is the format of this string, ie, for current user do I use [`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\` or `CURRENT_USER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379593%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#SE_REGISTRY_KEY)?

For a registry key is the object name just the path to the registry key or something else?

For example:

```
LPTSTR pObjectName = _T("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\MyAppName");
// or should it be...
LPTSTR pObjectName = _T("CURRENT_USER\\Software\\MyAppName");
```

Answer (score 2):

[Read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379579.aspx) for `SetNamedSecurityInfo()`:

> For descriptions of the string formats for the different object types, see [SE_OBJECT_TYPE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379593.aspx).

.

> SE_REGISTRY_KEY
>   Indicates a registry key. A registry key object can be in the local registry, such as CLASSES_ROOT\SomePath or in a remote registry, such as \ComputerName\CLASSES_ROOT\SomePath.
>
> The names of registry keys must use the following literal strings to identify the predefined registry keys: "CLASSES_ROOT", "CURRENT_USER", "MACHINE", and "USERS".

So the answer to your question is this:

```
LPTSTR pObjectName = _T("CURRENT_USER\\Software\\MyAppName");
```